# Given measure, show that countable additivity implies countable subadditivity

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $m: \Sigma \mapsto \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$, then I wish to show that

$$m(\bigsqcup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty m(A_j) \implies m(\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j) \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty m(A_j)$$

Where ($\bigsqcup$ emphasizes disjoint union)

(There is another post addressing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485734/countable-additivity-implies-countable-subadditivity) but it is neither instructive nor clear)

**Approach:**

---

1. Break things into disjoint unions

$\displaystyle{\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j = \bigsqcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \backslash (A_1\cup \ldots \cup A_{j-1}) = \bigsqcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \cap (A_1\cup \ldots \cup A_{j-1})^c = A_1 \sqcup A_2 \cap A_1^c \sqcup A^3 \cap A_1^c \cap A_2^c \sqcup \ldots}$

2. Take measure of both sides

$\displaystyle{m(\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j ) = m(A_1) + m( A_2 \cap A_1^c) + m( A^3 \cap A_1^c \cap A_2^c) + \ldots}$

At this point what can I do to conclude

$$m(\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j) \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty m(A_j)?$$

Comment: The point of the post you linked to is to reduce to the case of a disjoint union: That is, you can write $$\bigcup_i A_i = \bigcup_i B_i$$ with $B_i$ being pairwise disjoint. The process for doing this is to set $B_1 = A_1$, $B_2$ the part of $A_2$ that's not already covered, $B_3$ the part of $A_3$ that's not already covered, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you take $B_1=A_1$ and $B_{n+1}=A_{n+1}\cap(A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n)^c$ as you were thinking. Then, $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n}$, and also since $B_n\subseteq A_n$ we have $\mu(B_n)\leq \mu(A_n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Therefore, $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\mu\left(\bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n).$$

Comment: Hi, Since $A \backslash D = A\cap D^c$, should $B_{n+1} = A_{n+1} \cap (A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n)^c$ instead? And  I don't quite see $B_n \subseteq A_n$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Yes you are right. I have corrected it! $B_n\subseteq A_n$ because $B=A\cap C\subseteq A$ for any pair of sets $A,C$.

Comment: thanks everything checks out now